# oracle sql contain

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with values in columns like

```
colname
TMC_MCH,OTA_MCH,CONSOL_MCH,RETAIL_MCH,TOUROP_MCH,SPEC_MCH,QRACTO_MCH
RETAIL_MCH
RETAIL_MCH,CONSOL_MCH
CONSOL_MCH
OTA_MCH
```

I need to run query to fetch all rows contains RETAIL_MCH or CONSOL_MCH.
if i run query below i get result as below

```
select * from table111  where 
 (CONTAINS(table111.colname, 'RETAIL,CONSOL' , 1) > 0)

TMC_MCH,OTA_MCH,CONSOL_MCH,RETAIL_MCH,TOUROP_MCH,SPEC_MCH,QRACTO_MCH
RETAIL_MCH
RETAIL_MCH,CONSOL_MCH
CONSOL_MCH
```

but I need to exact search including underscore "_"

select * from table111  where
(CONTAINS(table111.colname, 'RETAIL_MCH,CONSOL_MCH' , 1) > 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONTAINS` is an Oracle text function, you can escape the underscore:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table111
WHERE  CONTAINS( colname, 'RETAIL\_MCH,CONSOL\_MCH', 1 ) > 0
```

Or, if you want to pass the string in unescaped then you could use `REPLACE` to add the escape characters:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table111
WHERE  CONTAINS( colname, REPLACE ( 'RETAIL_MCH,CONSOL_MCH', '_', '\_' ), 1 ) > 0
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table111 ( colname ) AS
SELECT 'TMC_MCH,OTA_MCH,CONSOL_MCH,RETAIL_MCH,TOUROP_MCH,SPEC_MCH,QRACTO_MCH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RETAIL_MCH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RETAIL_MCH,CONSOL_MCH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CONSOL_MCH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'OTA_MCH' FROM DUAL;

CREATE INDEX table111__colname__textidx ON table111(colname) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | COLNAME                                                              |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | TMC_MCH,OTA_MCH,CONSOL_MCH,RETAIL_MCH,TOUROP_MCH,SPEC_MCH,QRACTO_MCH |
> | RETAIL_MCH                                                           |
> | RETAIL_MCH,CONSOL_MCH                                                |
> | CONSOL_MCH                                                           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=90f23e5b6787f311c9d3d7123be1422e)*

Answer (score 0):

It would be probably simpler if you said which result you want. The way I understood it, maybe this helps:

```
select *
from table111
where instr(colname, 'RETAIL_MCH') > 0
   or instr(colname, 'CONSOL_MCH') > 0;
```

`OR` might need to be substituted by `AND` (depending on what you want).

Comment: No this is not solution which i am looking for as     'RETAIL_MCH,CONSOL_MCH'  is dynamic it can be  'RETAIL_MCH,OTA_MCH'

Comment: What does "dynamic" mean to you (in this context)? Can't you replace CONSOL_MCH with OTA_MCH?

Answer (score 0):

If you want *either* value, you would use:

```
where CONTAINS(table111.colname, 'RETAIL|CONSOL' , 1) > 0
```

If you want both:

```
where CONTAINS(table111.colname, 'RETAIL&CONSOL' , 1) > 0
```

You should pass the value in with the operator you want, instead of `,`.